# Why is my boolean returning an integer?

Tags: c++, boolean, increment

I'm fairly new to the programming world and I had a school assignment to create a simple program containing an if loop.
Basically, I want my code to return *true* if **a** is greater than 18, and *false* if **a** is less than 18. I also want **a** to increase by one each time **canTakeRoadtest** returns *false*. When I run my code all I get is

"I am 0 years old.

I can take my road test. 0"

I'm wondering why **bool canTakeRoadtest** is returning an integer, and why **a** isn't incrementing. Any help would be appreciated and I apologize for the simple question but we all start somewhere!

My coding environment is Eclipse Neon if it makes any difference.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
//Local Variables
    int a = 0;
    bool canTakeRoadtest = false;
//If Loop
    if (a >= 18) {
        canTakeRoadtest = true;
        cout << "I'm ready!\n";
    } else {
        canTakeRoadtest = false;
        cout << "I am " << a << " years old.\n";
        cout << "I can take my road test. " << canTakeRoadtest << endl;
        a++;

    }

    //return 0;

}
```

Comment: Under the hood, booleans are integers. 0 being false, anything else being true. Use a loop to increment the age until you hit 18.

Comment: @Tarik not true; e.g. some implementations only allow exactly `0x01` as the representation of `true`

Comment: @M.M Is this a standard behavior as per language specs?

Comment: @Tarik the language spec says nothing about how the compiler represents booleans under the hood. Different compilers can do do different things

Comment: "If Loop"? You mean "If Block"?

Answer (score 4):

Behind the scenes, every variable type in C++ has a number representation.  This makes sense because at the base level of a computer, all there is is numbers.  There are two main primitive data types that are (usually) represented as something other than a number, but are really just numbers.  The first one is **bool**, and the second one is **char**.

For example, if you set

```
bool myBool = true;
```

behind the scenes, it is really setting your variable to **1**.  Similarly, if you set

```
myBool = false;
```

it will be **0** behind the scenes.  The same rule applies for **chars**.  If you set

```
char myChar = 'a';
```

it really is setting the char to **97**.  Every character has a number representation, and you can see these if you look at this [table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

So, as to why **cout** is displaying the number representation of a **bool** rather than in "English", this is simply because whoever coded **iostream** decided that when you give it a **bool** it displays the number representation instead of the "English" representation.  The same does not apply for **chars**, however.  They will be represented as a character by **iostream**.

To fix **iostream** from printing out the incorrect representation, change your code from

```
cout << "I can take my road test. " << canTakeRoadtest << endl;
```

to

```
cout << "I can take my road test. false" << endl;
```

You could also use boolalpha, as Lovelace42 stated.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why my answer was downvoted?  I do not believe that there is anything wrong with it...  It honestly looks to me like a troll did it.  I am a relatively new user and would like to keep the little reputation I have.

Comment: I believe it may have been because you did not offer a solution towards the OP's problem, only explained why it happens. Still, i think it's a good thing to understand how things works instead of simply finding the "patch" to a problem.

Comment: @gooroo7 Thank you for the help. Its displaying the text I want, however **a** is still only staying as 0. Why is this?

Comment: @Danny I believe this is because you are trying to use `if` as a loop.  An if statement is not a loop, and it will simply see if the condition you gave it is true/false, run the code inside the `{ }` if the condition is true, and then move on.  The three main things that loop are `for` loops, `while` loops, and `do while` loops.  Here is some [information](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson3.html) on looping.

Answer (score 2):

Use boolalpha. By default bool values are integers, boolaplpha sets the bool flag to output its textual representation

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/

Or you can just change your cout statement.

```
if (a >= 18) {
    canTakeRoadtest = true;
    cout << "I'm ready!\n";
} else {
    canTakeRoadtest = false;
    cout << "I am " << a << " years old.\n";
    cout << "I can take my road test. false" << endl;
    a++;
}
```